# Svelte Native app images not displaying in preview

Tags: android, svelte, native

I've put together a very simple Svelte Native app to test it out. I'm having trouble with trying to display an image on my local machine when I preview the app with `ns preview`, if I display an image from a url however, it works fine:

This works:

```
<page>
    <actionBar title="Simple App" />
    <tabView>
        <tabViewItem title="Tab 1">
            <stackLayout>
                <image src="https://rb.gy/bwy8n" stretch="none"/>
            <stackLayout>
        </tabViewItem>        
    </tabView>
</page>
```

and I will see:

[image]

When I try the local image, with:

```
<image src="~/assets/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
```

I just get:

[image]

I've also tried the following with the same result:

```
<image src="~/assets/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
<image src="~/app/assets/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
<image src="../assets/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
<image src="./app/assets/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
<image src="smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/> <- also tried moving the file to the app directory
<image src="./smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/> 
<image src="~/app/smiley.jpg" stretch="none"/>
```

My file structure looks like this:

[image]

I'm testing this on an Android phone.